# Json Schema - How to make anyOf two or more properties required

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have this parent schema:

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "parcel": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "accountNumber": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "parcelNumber": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "propertyType": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "address": {
                    "$ref": "address.json#/definitions/address"
                },
                "coordinates": {
                    "$ref": "coordinates.json#/definitions/coordinates"
                }
            },
            "required": ["accountNumber", "parcelNumber"]
        }
    }
}
```

Following are the referenced sub-schemas:

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "address": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "addressString": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "addressType": {
                        "enum": ["residential", "business"]
                    }
                },
                "required": ["addressString"]
            }
        }
    }
}

    {
    "definitions": {
        "coordinates": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "latitude": {
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "longitude": {
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "projection": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": ["latitude ", "longitude", " projection"]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to apply the following conditions to the parent schema.

1. Either address or coordinates or both are provided.
2. It should fail the validation if neither address nor coordinates is provided.

Comment: Small comment:  You could use a single definitions object in your schema, containing all three sub-schemas.  They don't need to be in separate objects.

Comment: Another issue: I think your "id" property belongs under "properties"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `anyOf` solution works.  You can make it a little cleaner by separating the fixed required properties (accountNumber and parcelNumber) from the `anyOf` property group:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "accountNumber",
    "parcelNumber"
  ],
  "anyOf": [
    {"required" : ["address"]},
    {"required" : ["coordinates"]}
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "accountNumber": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "parcelNumber": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "propertyType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "addressString": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "addressType": {
          "enum": [
            "residential",
            "business"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "addressString"
      ]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "latitude": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "longitude": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "projection": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "latitude",
        "longitude",
        "projection"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a gist for reference:

http://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-05/markup/json?gist=f36d9a7e080c4d25dbbf09b7dd03137e

Answer (score 4):

This is how i implemented the solution.

```
"anyOf": [{
    "required": ["accountNumber", "parcelNumber", "coordinates"]
}, {
    "required": ["accountNumber", "parcelNumber", "address"]
}]
```